# submit form without submitting the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

This question is not Duplicate. Could you get it working and prove that it is duplicate ???

---

How can I submit the form below without submitting the page.

The Action in the below form has RESTful POST method.

e.g of consuming that API :

http://s22.postimg.org/79wp8rbv5/Capture.png

---

So, I have this static page. I need to submit the form without the page gets submitted. Any idea about that ?

```
<html>
<head>
<!-- jQuery v1.11.0 | (c) 2005, 2014 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/license -->

<script  src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).onload(function() {

    $("#submit-form-button").onclick(function() { submitForm(); });

});

function submitForm() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/somefeto/hr/emp/",
      data: { ENAME: $_POST['ENAME']},
      success: function() {
         alert("FORM SUBMITTED!");
      },
      dataType: 'html'
    });
 };

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action= "https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/somefeto/hr/emp/" method="POST">
   Employee: <input type="text" name="ENAME">
    <a href="#" id="submit-form-button">SUBMIT</a> 
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

---

After two hours, I manage to do it:

```
<html>
<head>
<!-- jQuery v1.11.0 | (c) 2005, 2014 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/license -->

<script  src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit-form-button").click(function() { submitForm(); });
});
function submitForm() {
var x = $("#ENAME").val();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/somefeto/hr/emp/",
      data: {  ENAME:  x },
      success: function() {
         alert("FORM SUBMITTED!");
      },
      dataType: 'html'
    });
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action= "https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/somefeto/hr/emp/" method="POST">
       Employee: <input id="ENAME" type="text" name="ENAME">
        <a href="#" id="submit-form-button">SUBMIT</a> 
    </form>

</body>    
</html>
```

Comment: set a target=name of a hidden iframe on the form

Answer (score 1):

You can use AJAX.

You'll need a clickable element.

```
<a href="#" id="submit-form-button">SUBMIT</a>
```

Now bind the javascript function to the button

```
$(document).onload(function() {


    $("#submit-form-button").onclick(function() { submitForm(); });


});
```

Put the ajax into a function

```
function submitForm() {

    $.ajax({

      type: "POST",
      url: "post_to.php",
      data: { name: $_POST['name'], addy: $_POST['addy'], email: $_POST['email'] },
      success: function() {

         alert("FORM SUBMITTED!");

      },
      dataType: 'html'

    });

 }
```

Comment: did not work. Thanks.

Comment: @user1116119 Though we really need more than just "did not work," I added all the code you will need to do this. Have you checked your javascript console for errors? Post them if you have any.

Comment: Thanks did not work. I will edit my question to show the code I used.

Comment: Sorry, I supposed that you test it. In the Console there is this error. Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function . I am quite weak in JS as I am Oracle developer not web.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Add this script in between `<head>` tag

```
    <script type="text/javascript">     
        window.onload=function(){
             document.forms["0"].submit();
        };
    </script>
```

Comment: Did not work. Thanks.